# How to enable sidebar on both monitors (in Ubuntu) on a dual monitor extended display?

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, sidebar

I am extending my display on my Ubuntu but the sidebar appears only on my primary display. Is there a way to enable the side bar/side panel/dock panel on both the monitors?
[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to **Settings > Appearance > Dock > Show on > All displays**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).